# What is the best method for managing many private YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

At my job we have a YouTube channel which has a large amount of videos that are unlisted which are part of a large unlisted playlist. We wish to control access to the videos on an invite/white-list basis as opposed to just an unlisted link share.

Now I understand that YouTube allows up to 50 people with valid Google/YouTube accounts to be authorized to do this for each video. HOWEVER this does not allow for playlists to have such luxury when it comes to controlling access.

My question: Is there a type of video manager where I can control who gets access to videos in bulk as opposed to just individually setting each video for each person? Because we might be dealing with 30+ accounts for various videos.

Comment: This sounds like something a CMS may handle nicely.

Comment: If I ran the companies website I would use just that but I was asking more about interfacing with YouTube itself.